# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog using the html option

Tags: development, javascript, modal-dialog

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx says that you can use the option `html` to display html text in a modal.

I have a string like this;

```
var html = '<div><strong>Test</strong> test</div>';
```

Passing this in as the `html` option causes the error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or
>   method 'getElementsByTagName'

So you can't pass a string into the html element. How can I convert my string into a format that the `html` option likes?

The string is being dynamically created on the sever and is being retrived via a WCF REST web service

Comment: Is it possible to use BOTH url and HTML? For instance, I want to get the Attach File dialogue but I also want to load some custom HTML to the modal since in my own modal I can't get the Attach File content to ONLY display what the modal displays...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

May not be the best wat but it works:

```
var test = "<div id='correspondence'>" + result + "</div>";
$('body').append(test);

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    html: document.getElementById('correspondence'),
    title: "Correspondence",
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    autoSize: true
});
```

Comment: Exactly. There is a mistake in msdn, and they are not even going to fix it. `html` is **not a string**, this is a **DOM element**. You can find evidence in comments to msdn article. Now I always read comments in msdn :).

Comment: Very important! If you want to make a non-trivial dialog (e.g form inputs) you may be tempted to define it in your html and reference it by id. This works **one time only** because a side-effect of `showModalDialog` deletes the DOM element! (such clever programmers at ms). If you want to open your dialog more than once, you must either create the element in code, or clone an existing element from the DOM. But beware because cloning will cause duplicate ids.

Comment: What if I want to add SP datepicker in the modal?

Answer (score 24):

Here's a better way than the code from John by using plain JavaScript (no need for jQuery) and without adding the element to the body manually:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = 'Hello World, I am the dialog content';

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    html: element,
    title: 'My Dialog Title',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    autoSize: true
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

The `html` option takes a DOM element rather than a string because of which you get this error. Try something like this:

```
var htmlElement = document.createElement('p');
var messageNode = document.createTextNode('Message');
htmlElement.appendChild(messageNode);
var options = {
    html: htmlElement,
    autoSize: true,
    allowMaximize: true,
    title: 'Title',
    showClose: true,
};
var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

The above code snippet has been taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx#2).

Comment: What if I want to add one SP datepicker in the modal?

Comment: @Harsh Not sure. You shoukd ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 6):

As shortcut you can use sg like:

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( { html : $( "<h1>asdf</h1>" ).get( 0 ) } );`

NOTE: if you have more than one tag you need to wrap everything into an embracing one otherwise only the first is shown:

`$( "<div><h1>asdf</h1><p>jkl;</p></div>" ).get( 0 )`

Comment: Only problem with this is that it creates a long heighten modal dialog

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example using jQuery : http://www.wawawum.com/blog/post/SharePoint-Modal-Dialog-from-HTML.aspx

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. In addition, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference - see [how to answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: -1   dead link!  @Benjamin

Comment: dead link @Benjamin