# SharePoint Visual Webpart Show contactus form in popup on button click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, popup

I am creating one sharepoint visual webpart where I have Send Inquiry button on the click of which Contact us Form should open. In that form I have submit button. By clicking on submit button I am adding new row in sharepoint list.

Can any one suggest me which Popup should I use over here?

If anyone has any URL than please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharePoint modal popup dialog**:

Create one page in the pages library >> add your custom *contact us* web part on that page >> (from the page on which you want to open the popup) on button click event open this page in popup.

Here are some references which will help to develop this popup:

- [Open a page in a SharePoint modal window](http://www.ericgregorich.com/blog/2013/12/30/open-a-page-in-a-sharepoint-modal-window)
- http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-Show-and-Hide-a-Modal-Pop-up-Dialog-in-a-SharePoint-2013-Page-or-a-Visual-WebPart
- [Open a different page within a modal dialog](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40827/open-a-different-page-within-a-modal-dialog)
- [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog using the html option](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27363/sp-ui-modaldialog-showmodaldialog-using-the-html-option)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884110/how-to-open-sharepoint-application-page-in-modal-dialog-popup-using-c
- http://wp.ahcheng.com/2013/04/09/calling-dialog-modal-form-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: but i have Internet(public facing) site. Will it work on that too?

Comment: Yes. Scripts will work.